# Make two nested folders mirror each other

Tags: python

I have two nested folders: `test_cases` dir with the test files (test.py) and
`test_features` dir with the feature files (test.feature).

I would like for the `test_features` dir to mirror the file structure of `test_cases`. To have a python script that creates any missing file struct and feature files in the `test_features` dir and removes any redundant file structure including empty dir that are not in `test_cases` dir.

Comment: Then why don't you add logic to remove stuff which shouldn't be there, and then ask a question if you have a _specific_ problem you need help with? It should not be hard to find existing questions about "remove files from A which are not in B" {which of course is isomorphic to set difference).

Comment: What's the question? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for tips. If you're looking for help with everything, that's too broad for Stack Overflow and you might want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost the same thing, except you need to search the feature folder for `.feature` files and remove them if no corresponding `.py` file is found. You also need to remove folders if they are empty after removing a file. For example:

```py
def remove_feature_file(file, root):
    os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
    while len(os.listdir(root)) == 0:
        os.rmdir(root)
        root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, os.pardir))

for file, root in find_feature_files(feature_files_path):
    rel_path = os.path.relpath(root, feature_files_path)
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    file_path = os.path.join(test_cases_path, file_name + '.py')
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        remove_feature_file(file, root)
```